# airflow dynamic task mapping with multiple chained expand calls

Tags: dynamic, airflow

I would like to build an airflow graph like this:

```
              ┌───►  task_2_1  ─────►  task_2_1
              │
              │
              │
task 1 ───────────►  task_2_2  ─────►  task_3_2
              │
              │
              │
              │
              └──►   task_2_N  ─────►  task_3_N
```

Where the number of vertical tasks (N) is controlled dynamically by the first step computation.

A possible solution would be:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task, task_group
from pendulum import datetime, now


@task
def task_1():
    return list(range(5))


@task
def task_2(task_num):
    return task_num


@task
def task_3(task_num):
    return task_num


with DAG(dag_id="my_dag", start_date=now(), schedule_interval=None) as dag:
    task_3.expand(task_num=task_2.expand(task_num=task_1()))
```

But the task_3 instances start to run only when all the task_2 instance have finished. I would rather group tasks by instances of task_2 and task_3 sharing the same task_num.
An intuitive solution would have been to use a taskgroup, but these do not have the expand method.

Comment: I've run into exactly the same issue just now! In my case `task_2` is a "wait for a random amount of time" function. What I've tried so far is somehow chaining tasks before calling `expand` on them, but I'm not sure I'm going in the right direction, I'm still getting my head around Airflow. Someting like this: `(task_2 >> task_3).expand(task_num=task_1())`. Does that make sense at all?

Comment: I have the exact same use case too. From here it seems like they were going to put it on task groups, but I haven't had luck yet -> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-42+Dynamic+Task+Mapping

Answer (score 4):

Dynamic task mapping on task groups (also called depth-first task execution) is not yet available in airflow (current version is 2.4.2)

Implementation is delayed to future version (see https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/22518)

A workaround consist in moving your task2 and task3 into a separate dag and running them by expanding a TriggerDagRunOperator task in the main dag.

Comment: Man, I was really hoping this was available. It looks like something similar may be available from this one... expanding on expand, but its complex enough I'm going to opt to have all the processes just wait for the first map to finish, then run my second map. https://marclamberti.com/blog/dynamic-task-mapping-in-apache-airflow/ for reference in the "Constant Parameters With Dynamic Task Mapping" section. I haven't tested that does what I want.

Comment: Mapping over a task group is now available and you can now call expand on task groups.

Check out the documentation here :
 https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html#mapping-over-a-task-group